# Unable to start rails server with an gem error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After I type rails s in terminal, I got this error:

> /Users/freefrog/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:196:in `method_missing': undefined local variable or method`mongoid' for Raceday::Application:Class (NameError)
>   Did you mean?  mongoize

what's that mean? It looks like something is wrong with gem file? but bundle show that everything goes well.

Comment: Can you share the railtie.rb file? The error means that you're trying to call `mongoid` method, but it's not defined. For instance, if you are doing something like `variable = mongoid` instead of `variable = 'mongoid'`, then Ruby will try to evaluate the method 'mongoid' and will assign it to 'variable'.

Comment: I have solved this issue, it is a typo... in application.rb file, `Mongoid.load!('./config/mongoid.yml')` M should be upper-case.